# PHP Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000

Tags: php, apache

I have problem in php with max_input_vars. When trying to submit form getting

```
[:error] [pid 10308] [client 127.0.0.1:37273] PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini.
```

I have changed max_input_vars default 1000 value in php.ini, and when doing php -i I am getting the changed value (e.g. 3000), but when submitting form getting the same error. Can somebody help with this?

Comment: Did you change it in the correct php.ini.... many installations use a separate php.ini for CLI and for the web sapi

Comment: restart your webserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On some distributions there are multiple php.ini files - one for cli, one for cgi and one for apache (or sapi).

If you use mod_php you might need to change /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini (this path is valid for Debian) and afterwards you must restart the webserver.

In order to find out which php.ini was used, you can create a small php script containing `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and execute it (using the webserver). There you will see which php.ini was used.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that there are usually 2 php.ini files, one for the CLI and one for the one used by your webserver/FPM. Running `php -i` from command line shows your the php.ini settings from the CLI php.ini, but that's not the one you need. So make sure to alter the other ini file and reload your webserver.

Use [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to show which ini is currently loaded and make sure to change that file.